# Sprig resets value on render

Tags: craft3, plugin-sprig

I Have a sprig component that has two variables, but the moment Sprig changes one of them, the other value resets. Please Help

products.twig

```
{% extends "_layout/base" %}

{% set wrapClass = 'category' %} 


{% block body %}

    <section class="spacer pt-6"></section>
    {% include "_shared/breadcrumbs" %}
    <section class="spacer pt-6"></section>
    {{sprig("_shared/sprig2", {count: 20 })}}

{% endblock %}
```

_sprig2.twig

```
{% set count = count ?? 12 %}
{% set offset = offset ?? 0 %}


<button sprig  s-val:count="{{ count + 3 }}">three more..
    {{count}}
</button>

    <button sprig s-val:offset="{{ offset + 3 }}">three more..
    {{offset}}
</button>


{{ sprig.script }}
```

In this example, If I click count, offset resets and if I do offset, the count resets, Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain state within your component either by using a hidden input field:

```
{{ hiddenInput('count', count) }}
```

Or by adding another `s-val` attribute to each button.

```
<button sprig s-val:count="{{ count + 3 }}" s-val:offset="{{ offset }}">
    ...
</button>

<button sprig s-val:offset="{{ offset + 3 }}" s-val:count="{{ count }}">
    ...
</button>
```

Since `s-val` is inherited, you can add it to a parent element for convenience.

```
<div s-val:count="{{ count }}" s-val:offset="{{ offset }}">
    <button>...</button>
    <button>...</button>
</div>
```